# Kafka Integration with Nagios

Tags: amazon-ec2

According to our infrastructure we want to monitor our Kafka service through Nagios.
I have one monitor server of Nagios and a client server where Kafka application is running and JMX_PORT is set 9999 for kafka metrics.Now I am able to monitor client server but I have no idea how to integrate kafka service for monitoring.
Can anyone help me to make understand step by step for changes?
Thanks in advance.